# PayPal Mobile Payments Library (iOS) log in button disable

Tags: ios, button, authentication, paypal-sandbox, disabled-control

I downloaded the PayPalMPL_1-6-5-iPhone_DevelopersPackage from paypal official website，then opened the demoApp project, run in iPad device, when I pressed the button [Pay with PayPal],  a view displayed, I can input my email and password, then pressed the button [Log In], every thing worked good. But someday the [Log In] button is disabled, I can't Log in and can't do anything from then on. 
It worked OK in iOS simulator all the time. 
I didn't change any code of the demoApp. The same problem occurred in my another application. WHY??? Who can help me? Thanks very much.

Comment: Add you code. What you have tried??

Comment: facing similar problem. have you solved thos problem @jiangjun.thanks in advance

Comment: @PathikGandhi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20016196/paypal-mpl-log-in-button-disabled